# Why are HashMap String values converted to uppercase?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have declared a Map as below,

```
private Map<String, String> mUnsavedFields = new HashMap<>();
```

If i add the following entry;

```
mUnsavedFields.put("username", "Batman");
```

it works as expected but when I go to get the value at the "username" key in a loop,

```
Iterator it = mUnsavedFields.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    Timber.d("Key(%s), Value(%S)", pair.getKey(), pair.getValue());
    it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
}
```

it returns it as "BATMAN" all uppercase. Why is this happening and how can I retain the exact formatting it went in with?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It can't happen, maybe you are modifying values somewhere else.

Comment: Collections don't modify the things put in them by themselves, that would be ridiculous.

Comment: And how are you getting the value at the `"username"` key ? your code ?

Comment: Please include more of your code. Most likely, you are calling `.toUpperCase()` at some stage (either before or after calling `put`).

Comment: I'm not calling .toUpperCase() anywhere, believe me as illogical and as stupid and impossible as it is, it is what I'm experiencing and haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Unless your code is uppercasing it, some external non-jvm code would have to be manipulating the jvm's memory in order for this to happen.  Can you post a Single file with a `main` that shows this problem?

Comment: @CaptRisky there's no way we can help, since you haven't posted a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: I'm getting the values in the above loop which all values are uppercased, I'm not familiar with the loop for maps so I'm guessing it has something to do with it. If I get a single value individually its fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the %S format placeholder captalizes the input argument.

The captalized result is only the print shown in the console, the value is the original.

Use

```
"Key(%s), Value(%s)"
```

Comment: Wow what a noob mistake right there lol, cheers mate, all sorted ;)

Answer (score 6):

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax):

> Conversions denoted by an upper-case character (i.e. 'B', 'H', 'S', 'C', 'X', 'E', 'G', 'A', and 'T') are the same as those for the corresponding lower-case conversion characters **except that the result is converted to upper case**

(emphasis mine)

You use %S, so it converts to uppercase.

Comment: Cheers mate for your help